# Image Processing - Skimage or other

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, scikit-image

I am new to image processing. I am trying out a few experiments.

1. I have binarized my image with otsu
2. Found connected pixels with skimage

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import skimage

im = Image.open("DMSO_Resized.png")
imgr = im.convert("L")
im2arr = np.array(imgr)
arr2im = Image.fromarray(im2arr)

thresh = skimage.filters.threshold_otsu(im2arr)
binary = im2arr > thresh
connected = skimage.morphology.label(binary)
```

I'd now like to count the number of background pixels that are either "completely" covered by other background pixels or "partially" covered.

```
For example, pixel[1][1] is partially covered 
1 0 2
0 0 0
3 0 8
AND
For example, pixel[1][1] is completely covered 
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
```

Is there a skimage or other package that has a method to do these ? Or would I have to implement them as an array processing loop ?

[image: Sample image]

[image: Binarized image]

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import morphology

bad_connection = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                           [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                           [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                           [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                           [1, 0, 0, 0, 1]], dtype=np.uint8)

expected_good =  np.array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                           [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=np.uint8)


another_bad   = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                          [1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
                          [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                          [1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
                          [1, 0, 0, 0, 1]], dtype=np.uint8)

another_good  = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=np.uint8)

footprint = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                      [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                      [1, 0, 0, 0, 1]], dtype=np.uint8)
```

Outputs (incorrect or not as expected):
[image: Outputs]

Comment: Please share your images if you'd like some assistance - else we don't know what you are referring to. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Added a sample image and edited code to show image load. Thanks

Comment: your picture contains biological cells. what do you call "background cells"? what do you mean by "covered"? do you mean occluded, or do you mean something else?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz - I have edited the question. I meant background pixel not cell.  Sorry about that typo !

After binarization, 0 is a background pixel as its not part of the cell. A 0 pixel is "covered" if all the pixels next to it ( left, right, up, down, diagonal x 4) are all 0 pixels too. Does that clarify your question ? Thanks

Comment: You appear to have shared a JPEG. Yet your code suggests you are using a PNG? If you have binarised and labelled your image, please share those images too. If you would like folk to help you, make it easy for them. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I shared the png. Its stackoverflow thats making it to a jpeg. I'll try to see how to upload it as "png". Sorry. Trying to figure this out.

Comment: sounds like you want morphology operations like open/close.

Comment: @MarkSetchell - The original image was 1.3MB so Imgur automatically made it jpg. I have now edited it to be a smaller png and binarized version.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I tried with open/close using default and custom footprint. But,  I am unable to generate the expected output. I have edited my question to show 2 examples of expected responses. 

In the case of `bad_connection`, only pixels[0][2] and pixels[1][2] are 0 and only surrounded by other 0s. So they should be counted. Rest shouldnt be

In case of `another_bad`, no 0 pixel is surrounded by only 0 pixels, hence none of them is counted.

Maybe my custom footprint is incorrect !